# kafka startup failure (version 0.8.0 beta1 )

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to start a kafka service with zookeeper version (3.3.6) on standalone mode (on ec2).
So I run 1) sbt update 2) sbt package 3)sbt assembly-package-dependency    and then start the zookeeper service, and then the kafka server. However, I received the following error message:
for kafka server log:

```
ERROR Error while electing or becoming leader on broker 0 (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:670)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.connect(BlockingChannel.scala:57)
    at kafka.controller.ControllerChannelManager.kafka$controller$ControllerChannelManager$$addNewBroker(ControllerChannelManager.scala:84)
    at kafka.controller.ControllerChannelManager$$anonfun$1.apply(ControllerChannelManager.scala:35)
    at kafka.controller.ControllerChannelManager$$anonfun$1.apply(ControllerChannelManager.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:81)
    at kafka.controller.ControllerChannelManager.<init>(ControllerChannelManager.scala:35)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.startChannelManager(KafkaController.scala:503)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.initializeControllerContext(KafkaController.scala:467)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.onControllerFailover(KafkaController.scala:215)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:89)
    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.elect(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:53)
    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$LeaderChangeListener.handleDataDeleted(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:106)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient$6.run(ZkClient.java:549)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread.run(ZkEventThread.java:71)
```

for zookeeper log:

```
    2014-07-15 15:49:22,996 - INFO  [ProcessThread:-1:PrepRequestProcessor@419] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1473b82f52e0004 type:create cxid:0x57 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/topics/edwintest Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/topics/edwintest
2014-07-15 15:49:23,102 - INFO  [ProcessThread:-1:PrepRequestProcessor@419] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1473b82f52e0004 type:create cxid:0x59 zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/topics/edwintest Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/topics/edwintest
2014-07-15 15:49:23,109 - INFO  [ProcessThread:-1:PrepRequestProcessor@419] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1473b82f52e0004 type:create cxid:0x5b zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/topics/edwintest Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/topics/edwintest
2014-07-15 15:49:23,215 - INFO  [ProcessThread:-1:PrepRequestProcessor@419] - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x1473b82f52e0004 type:create cxid:0x5d zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/topics/edwintest Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/topics/edwintest
```

for kafka producer log:

```
[2014-07-15 15:49:23,107] INFO Fetching metadata from broker id:0,host:localhost,port:9092 with correlation id 23 for 1 topic(s) Set(edwintest) (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
[2014-07-15 15:49:23,107] INFO Connected to localhost:9092 for producing (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
[2014-07-15 15:49:23,111] INFO Disconnecting from localhost:9092 (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
[2014-07-15 15:49:23,111] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic edwintest ->
No partition metadata for topic edwintest due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [edwintest]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2014-07-15 15:49:23,112] ERROR Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: Failed to fetch topic metadata for topic: edwintest (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2014-07-15 15:49:23,112] INFO Back off for 100 ms before retrying send. Remaining retries = 0 (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2014-07-15 15:49:23,213] INFO Fetching metadata from broker id:0,host:localhost,port:9092 with correlation id 24 for 1 topic(s) Set(edwintest) (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
[2014-07-15 15:49:23,213] INFO Connected to localhost:9092 for producing (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
[2014-07-15 15:49:23,217] INFO Disconnecting from localhost:9092 (kafka.producer.SyncProducer)
[2014-07-15 15:49:23,218] WARN Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic edwintest ->
No partition metadata for topic edwintest due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [edwintest]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException  (kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo)
[2014-07-15 15:49:23,219] ERROR Failed to send requests for topics edwintest with correlation ids in [17,24] (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
[2014-07-15 15:49:23,219] ERROR Error in handling batch of 1 events (kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread)
kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:90)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:104)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:87)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:254)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:66)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:44)
```

my `/etc/hosts` config

```
127.0.0.1       ip-172-32-1-95 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

**my server.properties file**

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The port the socket server listens on
port=9092

# Hostname the broker will bind to and advertise to producers and consumers.
# If not set, the server will bind to all interfaces and advertise the value returned from
# from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#host.name=localhost

# The number of threads handling network requests
num.network.threads=2

# The number of threads doing disk I/O
num.io.threads=2

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=1048576

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=1048576

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# The directory under which to store log files
log.dir=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The number of logical partitions per topic per server. More partitions allow greater parallelism
# for consumption, but also mean more files.
num.partitions=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the flush of data to disk. This is the most
# important performance knob in kafka.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data is at greater risk of loss in the event of a crash.
#    2. Latency: Data is not made available to consumers until it is flushed (which adds latency).
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
log.flush.interval.ms=1000

# Per-topic overrides for log.flush.interval.ms
#log.flush.intervals.ms.per.topic=topic1:1000, topic2:3000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log as long as the remaining
# segments don't drop below log.retention.bytes.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=536870912

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.cleanup.interval.mins=1

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=1000000

# metrics reporter properties
kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs=5
kafka.metrics.reporters=kafka.metrics.KafkaCSVMetricsReporter
kafka.csv.metrics.dir=/tmp/kafka_metrics
# Disable csv reporting by default.
kafka.csv.metrics.reporter.enabled=false </code>
```

**my zookeeper config  zoo.cfg**

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
```

I tried to delete all the information for kafka and zookeeper under /tmp/zookeeper or /tmp/kafka-logs, and restart everything, but still receive the same error.

Comment: I am certainly not an operations guy, but your hosts file looks odd. Have you altered it for some purpose? If you're running single broker the problem is very likely is that you have misconfigured loopback interface.

Answer (score 2):

Cool! I guess you are running kafka-console-producer to publish a message to a topic "edwintest". Before running your producer, create the topic using this command

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 5 --topic edwintest
```

And the start your console producer. Hope this should fix your problem.

**[EDIT]**
Obviously you have to ensure your ec2 security groups are updated properly to open zk and kafka broker ports for producers.