# Zookeeper having KeeperException but Kafka able to create topics and produce/consume

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I recently setup Kafka on a single node CDH 5 setup with the aim of playing with it on a single node before moving to a real cluster. Initially, I just started the zookeeper server, with the kafka server and it was all fine. I could see that zookeeper was running on 2181 while Kafka was running on 9092. I then created a topic, and started the consumer and the producer and the consumer could see the messages the producer was sending.

With happiness on my face, I moved to the tab with zookeeper logs and saw this:

```
[2015-05-27 16:46:07,016] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14d97bf0a020002 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0x1f txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/test-consumer-group/ids Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/test-consumer-group/ids (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2015-05-27 16:46:07,021] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14d97bf0a020002 type:create cxid:0x3 zxid:0x20 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/test-consumer-group Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/test-consumer-group (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2015-05-27 16:46:07,306] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14d97bf0a020002 type:create cxid:0x19 zxid:0x24 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/test-consumer-group/owners/test Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/test-consumer-group/owners/test (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2015-05-27 16:46:07,307] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14d97bf0a020002 type:create cxid:0x1a zxid:0x25 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/test-consumer-group/owners Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/test-consumer-group/owners (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2015-05-27 16:47:06,961] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14d97bf0a020002 type:setData cxid:0x24 zxid:0x29 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/test-consumer-group/offsets/test/0 Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/test-consumer-group/offsets/test/0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2015-05-27 16:47:06,963] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x14d97bf0a020002 type:create cxid:0x25 zxid:0x2a txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers/test-consumer-group/offsets Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/test-consumer-group/offsets (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

It looks like zookeeper is not able to find a node for . . . stuff. But, if that's the case, why do all my commands work? I am able to create a topic, and then produce some data for it while the consumer subscribed to it gets the data too?

If it helps, my zookeeper version is 3.4.6 and my Kafka version is 0.8.2.1. And oh, the path /tmp/zookeeper exists.

Comment: This log messages might be old. If the node is not found then it creates a new znode that is why you are able to see those nodes and all your commands are working.

Comment: This has a similar solution to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767337/kafka-startup-failure-version-0-8-0-beta1

Comment: Have noticed this on newer Kafka servers were being added to cluster, it is probably syncing up what is on ZK, nothing to worry as it is just INFO. The exception could probably also be it was present already when Kafka was trying to create it.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same issue.

```
Exiting due to: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /consumers/test-group/offsets/packets/0.
```

I solved my issue.

- Make sure your zookeeper and kafka broker are running.
- Yes you can create topic and producer/consumer will work.
- To solve the error you must have a consumer with consumer-group which is subscribed to that topic.

In, your case it will be consumer with consumer-group `test-consumer-group` and subscribed to topic `Test`